# Accessing another word document TextBox

Tags: vba, ms-word

In my word "sheet", I have a **CommandButton** of which, when clicked, triggers a certain part of code which basically is about opening a second word document and inserting some informations from the current one (**Document1**) into the second one (**Document2**) **TextBox**.

I have **String** variables containing text in one word document (e.i. **Document1**). I am opening a second document (e.i. **Document2**). Then, I need to reach a specific **TextBox** from the **Document2** and insert into it the value of one of the **String** variables I already have.

That being said, I can't access that second document (**Document2**) since I always gets the "4160 error" which result of the file name being incorrect.

Therefore, how can I access my second document (**Document2**) **TextBox** and insert into it a specific value I already have?

My code as follow (simplified to one variable since it'll be the same for every other):

---

```
Private Sub btn1_Click()
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document
    Dim name As String

    strFile = "C:\Users\WhateverUser\Desktop\WhateverFolder\Document2.docx"

    name= txtBoxName.Text
    'This comes from the first document (Document1) which is correct.

    ' Opening another Word document (Document2)
    Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(strFile)
    WordApp.Visible = True

    'Here is the problem
    'Trying to access the Document2 TextBox (txtBoxNameDoc2) with various ways but I always get the Incorrect File Name Error

    'First I tried
    Documents("Document2.docx").Bookmarks("txtBoxNameDoc2").Range.Text = name
    'Then I tried

    Documents("Document2.docx").txtBoxNameDoc2.Text = name
    'And after those, I went looking on internet and tried what I could find but none did work.

End Sub
```

Comment: Great job on your question. I have a pending edit to improve your formatting-- I recommend you do this in the future as it helps people read your question and hopefully get you an answer more quickly. I also added more related tags-- again, the goal is to help your question be seen by the right people.

Comment: In the code you have provided, you have not assigned any value to the variable `txtBoxNameDoc2`. That appears to be an error. Also, are you certain that the document name is "Document2.docx"?  If that is incorrect, it will also be an error.

Comment: First, thank you @DavidSchwartz for your edit no my formatting ! I'll look into it for the other questions I may ask during the years to come.

Comment: As for @DavidZemens, the ' txtBoxNameDoc2 ' would be the name of the TextBox in the Document2. On the Document2.docx, it's not the name, I used Doc1 and Doc2 as an exemple but yes, I am pretty sure of the name of the document since I copied it using the "rename" (F2) option and pasted it directly in my code.

Comment: If the `txtBoxNameDoc2` is a string literal, it needs to be enclosed in quotes...

Comment: It is in my code, that being said, retranscripting it here (changing the variables names and stuff) made me make that mistake. That being said, the `txtBoxNameDoc2` equivalent in my code is duly enclosed by quotes.
Therefore, I added them in the "original" post.

Comment: @OUO Just a friendly reminder, don't forget to accept an answer when your question is answered. And even if it doesn't fix your issue, I recommend upvoting high-quality and helpful answers, of which I believe DavidZemens' is one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Sorry for that oversight, as we can see, it's my first time here so I still have a lot to catch up with. I have upvoted the post since I also think that it is an helpful answer. That being said, it won't be displayed until I have 15+ rep. 
I was off yesterday so don't mind me if I was not looking here yesterday, we have a holiday on the  24 here.
Now that I'm back, I'm looking into it, will test the new method DavidZemens commented and I will give you a feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can speculate at some errors in the coding you have provided above, but if this line works without returning an error:

```
Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(strFile)
WordApp.Visible = True
```

THen you should be able to do:

```
WordDoc.Bookmarks(txtBoxNameDoc2).Range.Text = name
```

This is because you have already opened "Document2.docx" **and** furthermore you have specifically assigned it to the `WordDoc` object variable. Because you have done this, you do not need to explicitly reference it from the `Documents` collection, as you are doing in your original code.

**NB:** This assumes that `txtBoxNameDoc2` is valid string that identifies a bookmark in the `WordDoc` document.  If it should be interpreted as a literal string (i.e., it is the actual *name* of the bookmark, then you need to qualify it with quotation marks, like:

```
WordDoc.Bookmarks("txtBoxNameDoc2").Range.Text = name
```

**If this continues to raise an error, then the named bookmark doesn't exist.**

It **is** possible to assign a bookmark to a TextBox object. Bookmarks do not "automatically" exist in a document, so first you have to ensure such a bookmark exists. You can review these and assign them (if they do not exist) through the ribbon).

Bookmarks don't exist unless you create them. You've assumed that the object's name can also refer to a Bookmark, and while it *can*, first you need to *create* the bookmark and assign it the name by which you want to refer it.

Comment: I had tried this `WordDoc.Bookmarks("txtBoxNameDoc2").Range.Text = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("txtBoxName").Range.Text` before but that was before I realized that I could only do the name = txtBoxName.Text and then use the variable instead. That being said, it weren't working. I'll give it a try now to see though, maybe it was my former code that was wrong and that this method should now work.

Comment: I tried it back but it is now giving me the 5941 error which is that a member of the required collection doesnt exist.

Comment: Since the _name_ property of my TextBox in _Document2_ is exactly `txtBoxNameDoc2`, I would have guess there was one. That being said, you said in your answer that you weren't certain that it could be done (bookmarking "a control like a TextBox"). Therefore, I guess that I can't use that property (_name_) of the TextBox control as a bookmark and, furthermore, just can't bookmark a TextBox. That brings me to another question then : Is there a way to access my _Document2_ TextBox ".Text" property from _Document1_ and then change it for what I want **without** using the bookmark method?

Comment: The `Name` property of an object is just that: the object's `.Name`. It is not any sort of "bookmark" (i.e., just because Word supports a Bookmarks collection, do not assume that named objects are intrinsically existing in that collection -- they are not!).

Comment: In order to use the bookmark method, you would first have to ensure that such a bookmark exists. Does such a bookmark exist? If not, have you referenced the textbox as a member of the `WordDoc.Shapes` collection, i.e., `WordDoc.Shapes("txtBoxNameDoc2")`?

Comment: FYI, I have just tested this and it **is** possible to assign a bookmark to a normal TextBox shape. But first you have to assign the bookmark (this can be done manually, through the ribbon).

Comment: You were right, I had forget about it. Tried it and it worked. Like you said, I had to assing the bookmark through the ribbon. Therefore, this question can be marked as resolved by DavidZemens.